# custom setMessage dialog TextView cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm trying to print a message from my dialogBox, this message is coming from an API, and I pretend to print that in a TextView that I have set for it, below is what I'm trying to do and the error log:

```
close = new AlertDialog.Builder(LembrarSenha.this);

close.setCancelable(true);

close.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

String msg = mNovaSenhaRest.getNovaSenha(value).getMsg();

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);

TextView informativo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.informacao);
informativo.setText(msg); // Line 149

close.setMessage((CharSequence) informativo);

close.setView(view);
```

The Log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
10-14 16:54:25.048  22956-22956/br.com. W/System.err﹕ at br.com..LembrarSenha$asyncTask$1.run(LembrarSenha.java:149)
```

(LembrarSenha.java:149) = "informativo.setText(msg);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you initialize your TextView as:

```
TextView informativo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.informacao);
```

?

Because you're trying to add a custom view to the dialog. You inflate your view, but when you initialize your TextView, you're not looking it up in your custom layout.

Comment: Yes Mike and I did, and the new error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence`

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to add a TextView as a message to the dialog(And this should be a String, CharSequence, etc.). You will never be able to cast a View to a CharSequence object. And since you add a custom layout to the dialog, you don't have to add a message to the dialog itself, because you set this message to your custom layout's TextView. Try to remove the close.setMessage((CharSequence) informativo); line